# Regex to match anchor text but not <a href link

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex pattern that matches a certain word (`carrots`) in a link's anchor text, but not when the word is in the <a href link itself.

Any uses of `carrots` when it is not in an href, or is in the anchor text, is what I want to match.

```
carrots (<- matches, ok)
carrot
carrots and potatoes (<- matches, ok)
potatoes and carrots (<- matches, ok)
<a href="/carrots%20and%20potatoes">carrots and potatoes</a> (<- matches 'carrots' in link and anchor text, but I only want the one in anchor text)
<a href="/carrots">carrots and potatoes</a> (see above, it matches both but I want anchor text only)
```

The regex I have so far is:

```
~<a .*?">|\bcarrots\b
```

Here is the regex101 I am using for testing: https://regex101.com/r/1RKDEa/1

This is also in JavaScript (to make a Regexp out of afterwards), so I can't use *SKIP and *FAIL.

Comment: Regex isn't the answer to everything that is text. There are far better ways to meet your objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use negative look-behind: `(?<!\<[^>]*)\bcarrots\b`

Not all browsers [support](https://caniuse.com/?search=lookbehind) it though

```js
const data = html.innerHTML.replace(/(?<!\<[^>]*)\bcarrots\b/g, "<mark>$&</mark>")

html.innerHTML = data;
text.textContent = data;
```

```html
<div id="html" style="white-space:pre">carrots
carrot
carrots and potatoes
potatoes and carrots

<a href="website.com/carrots%20and%20potatoes">carrots and potatoes</a>

<a href="/carrots">carrots and potatoes</a></div>


<div id="text" style="white-space:pre;border:1px solid black"></div>
```

Comment: You might want to mention that Safari doesn't support that feature yet.